# How to have a cell that displays the cumulative value of all values entered in another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I want to have a cell on my spreadsheet that updates in a cumulative manner, in response to values being changed in another cell. What would the code for this cell be?

For example the original value of cell B2 is 3 and cell C2 shows the cumulative value of all numbers entered into cell B2. So initially C2 will show 3. Once the value of B2 is changed to 10, C2 displays 13 and so on.

Comment: I believe this problem would require a [circular reference](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/circular-reference.html). Since number of iterations is limited you won't be able to create persistent solution

Answer (score 2):

This will require VBA.

Something like this would work, it goes in the `Sheet1` module through the VBA editor*. You can change the sheet name and ranges as needed. -

```
Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("C2") = Range("C2").Value + target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

However, this will error if the target is non-numeric. So you need to handle the errors like this -

```
Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(target.Value) = False Then GoTo Error:
        If IsNumeric(Range("C2").Value) = False Then GoTo Error:
        Range("C2") = Range("C2").Value + target.Value
        Exit Sub
    Else: Exit Sub
    End If

Error:
    MsgBox ("Use a number!")
End Sub
```

**To get to the VBA editor, you must go to the office button, excel options and in the popular tag, place a checkmark in the box next to `Show Developer tab in the Ribbon`. Then close that out, go to the developer tab and click the `Visual Basic` button on the far left. The editor will open up and you will need to double click the `Sheet1` (or whatever sheet this is on) module on the left pane.*

Answer (score 0):

You CAN do this, sort of, and with HUGE pitfalls, without VBA.

But who would want to when he reads how?

First, perhaps you have a formula, `=A1+B1` in A1. And in B1, nothing at all. You want what you asked for.

Second, you set things up in Excel to do this. There's two main parts:

1. Go to `File | Options | Formulas`, first part, right at the very top and, for fun, TO the right side of the top. Check the checkbox to `Enable iterative calculation`. Then place a "1" in the box under it for `Maximum Iterations`. That last part is just as important as the first part. Click `OK` at the bottom and return to the sheet.
2. If you wish to proceed with doing this right then, leave `Calculation` "Automatic" so calculation happens. Start entering numbers in B1, one after the other. You type one of them, then press Enter, and observe the formula in A1 to be working. Maybe your idea is to add up checks for a bank deposit and you don't prefer better ways. This will do it. The **MOMENT** you are done entering, EITHER do one more entry in B1, that of typing "0" and pressing Enter, and you can do any other work in the spreadsheet as you please, OR you can turn `Calculation` "off" by changing it to "Manual" and never using it again until you are ready to enter more things in B1. That's... not very useful...

So, you would have to always remember to enter the "0" in B1 as a last step before doing any other spreadsheet work. No simple going back and forth as you please. This is an ironclad requirement.

Your formula in A1 would work even if B1 had a formula like `=C1`. Then you'd have to treat C1 like you were treating B1, above.

However, the more complex, complicated, convoluted, and far-ranging the formula in A1 and EVERY cell that feeds the formula, the more difficult it would be to control something changing unexpectedly (undesirably), and more important, it would approach near impossible to zero all the cells before doing ANY other work in the spreadsheet. Not only that, the Manual Calculation option would become just as difficult to use as before actually initiating it, you'd still have to zero all the possible inputs to A1.

So... VBA.

Two things to mention:

1. Let's say you did the simple example above and typed "2, 4, 9, 24, 2, and 83" in B1. A1 would become:  2, 6, 15, 39, 41, 124. All good so far. Say you left the 83 in B1 and typed something, anything at all in D3, then pressed Enter. Calculation runs and another "83" is added to A1 bringing its total to 207. Not good. That's why you finish a typing run in B1 with "0", then Enter. So every time Excel calculates anything (and it will always include A1 in that), it adds another "0" to the total leaving it unchanged. But if you don't have "0" there, it adds other things and the total keeps adding up for no good (for you) reason. Another terror that could happen is what if you type something in B1 that causes an error in A1? Well, surely, you just delete it and all is good, eh? No. The error in A1 persists. It ain't going away due to anything happening in B1. So... what if you clear the error's cause in B1, maybe going to A1 and pressing `F2-Edit`, then Enter would return it to the pre-error value? No. It begins again with A1=0 and adding whatever is currently in B1. So you lose EVERYTHING you've done to that point. THAT could be a useful way to clear A1 and start again, but it's a terror every keystroke as you wait for a typo that would hammer it.
2. Not any kind of further problem. The ones I encountered trying out the idea are all talked about. This one has to do with the Excel Option settings you changed, specifically the `Maximum Iterations` value. It would seem that's something like "let's make it 100 so we can do this for 100 entries, then it will stop on its own." But that is definitely NOT what happens. What happens is that Excel performs the formula that many times. So have "0" in A1, "100" for `Maximum Iterations`, and enter "28" in B1. "2800" appears in A1 as Excel added "28" to the value in A1 (0) 100 times, reaching "2800." So you definitely need a "1" for that value for your stated purpose.

*By the way, this is 2021 and I am using Build 2109. It is possible, though not likely, that circularity worked differently, and enough differently, in 2014, that this would not have worked then. But it does today so could be of interest to folks for a while, or a long time if the way circularity works does not get changed any time soon.*