# I would like one cell to add within the same cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to have one cell calculate over and over again multiple times.
Here is an example:

If I type 45 in cell d6. I want to be able to type 67 into the same cell d6 and it add both the previous 45 plus the 67 together without me having to type it into another cell and do a SUM function.

I do not know exactly what to try so any ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: You would need to "fake" the appearance using a macro or Visual Basic program to overwrite your entry.  When you type into a cell, it overwrites whatever was previously there.

Comment: the better questions is why you want to do this... it will be confusing what has been included vs what hasn't been.

Comment: [adapt this](http://superuser.com/questions/810753/how-to-have-a-cell-that-displays-the-cumulative-value-of-all-values-entered-in-a/810787#810787)

Answer (score 0):

You can do addition in a single cell without use of the `SUM` function.  Try entering this into your cell `D6`:

```
=45+67
```

Now, if you're asking if it's possible to type `67` into a cell, press `Enter` or otherwise navigate out of the cell, then return to the same cell and type another value and have it added, then answer is it can't be done (without using complicated VBA programming).

However, something that is close and might work provide a solution in your case is the following:

1. In cell `A1`, type `=SUM(A2:A10)`.
2. Start entering numbers in `A2`, pressing **Enter** after each (you're selection will move down to cells `A3`, `A4`, etc.)

As you do this the sum in `A1` will be updated with the running total, but all you need to do is continue entering numbers, pressing **Enter** after each.  You'd obviously need to extend the range referenced in cell `A1` if you wished to enter numbers beyond cell `A10`.

Comment: You can reference a column so one does not need to worry about how many rows are referenced.  E.g. =sum(A:A).